# Integrate Google Analytics on Ionic WooCommerce App

Tags: ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3

I want to integrate Google Analytics on mine Ionic / WooCommerce App, so I added a Google Analytics plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics
npm install --save @ionic-native/google-analytics
```

I saw this codes on ionic framework so I added them on the `app.component.ts`:

```
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';

constructor(private ga: GoogleAnalytics) { }

...

this.ga.startTrackerWithId('YOUR_TRACKER_ID')
.then(() => {

     alert('Google analytics is ready now');

      this.ga.trackView('test');

     // Tracker is ready

     // You can now track pages or set additional information such as AppVersion or UserId

   })

   .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e));
```

I added tracker Id…

After running this on the browser the console logs what I got was `GoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId`, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include `cordova.js` or run in a `device/simulator`:

```
cordovaWarn @ util.js:66
app.component.ts:155 Error starting GoogleAnalytics cordova_not_available).
```

So I produced an Apk tested on a device then the console log was (Google analytics is ready now). I checked the analytics dashboard still showing 0 users, 0 device.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in the browser you are not in a cordova context.
You need to wrap that code inside a platfom ready event like so:

```
constructor(platform: Platform, private ga: GoogleAnalytics) {
   ///
   platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.ga.startTrackerWithId('YOUR_TRACKER_ID')
      .then(() => {
         alert('Google analytics is ready now');
         this.ga.trackView('test');
         // Tracker is ready
        // You can now track pages or set additional information such as AppVersion or UserId

      })
      .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e));

   });
   ///
}
```

This means this will only execute when you are in a device context.

However, you can choose to implement GA in Web way by putting the GA scripts in your index.html, import typings for GA and it should work in all platforms and environments

Comment: still the same 0 user, 0 device

Comment: Like I said, this will only work in a device. if you want to test from dev environement, you need to add the GA <script>//...</script> in your html

Comment: i Tested it on a device still showing 0 device, 0 users.... hope its not how i set the GA account up.

Comment: seriously in need of Help.

Comment: Try the other approach (by inserting the GA scripts in your index.html) if that doesn't work then the problem is with you GA account

Comment: can you give me ideas on how to create GA account cause the previous i created was through firebase. Thanks

Comment: just go to your GA console and create a new TAG there

Comment: @Mehdi - Ionic states it works in browser: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-analytics, than how do we achieve that, I have the same issue

Comment: @Mehdi - and platform.ready runs in every context, in regular desktop browser will say: "desktop"